# Is there a newsletter service that allows me to use multiple separate RSS feeds to combine the content of my newsletter?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've found services that let me combine these feeds as one feed but I want them to be separate because I need to place the content of the feeds to different locations in the layout.

If this is not possible is there a newsletter service that let's me include an external HTML page inside a newsletter?

With this solution I could generate the HTML content elsewhere and then just simply fetch the HTML content automatically. This needs to be automated because newsletters are sent twice a day to thousands of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple separate RSS feeds in [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) by using FEED merge tag http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-any-blog-post-to-a-regular-campaign.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this process with a combination of [FlipRSS](https://fliprss.com) and Mailchimp or FlipRSS and Campaign Monitor. It allows you to pull in individual RSS feeds and only send these based on individual subscriber preferences.